# Python search for file name in directory

Tags: python, string, substring

How can I get the confirmation that the searched file exist, like it would do a bash script:

```
ls -l SOURCE | egrep PART_OF_FILENAME
```

> result:  the complete file name found.

when I get result of this in python:

```
import os
PART_OF_FILENAME in os.listdir(SOURCE)
```

> return False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `listdir` method returns an list of file names, using `in` with it will check if the exact specified file name is part of the list, as opposed to checking if the specified file name exists as a substring in any of the elements in the list.

Instead, you can loop through each element in the list and search for the given substring, like so:

```py
def searchSubstringInList(list, substring):
    for element in list:
        if (substring in element):
            return element
```

Then `searchSubstringInList(os.listdir(source), 'PART_OF_FILENAME')` will get you the full file name.

Answer (score -1):

ternary operators should do

```py
import os
print('File found!' if PART_OF_FILENAME in os.listdir(SOURCE) else 'Not found')
```